# Register Wicket application in Weblogic 11g and OIM

Tags: weblogic, single-sign-on, wicket, identity

I'm using WebLogic 11g server, OIM (Oracle identity Manager), and I created a new web application on Wicket 6 as a module. When I execute my application in WebLogic server `http://192.168.112.31:7001/WicketReport` I receive a **403 Error**.

My `web.xml` file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <display-name>Wicket Web Application</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>Application</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>applicationClassName</param-name>
            <param-value>kz.ecc.wicketreport.pages.Application</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Application</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file/>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I couldn't find any tutorial or instructions that describe how to do this. Please show me what I need to do or some steps to achieve it.

**UPDATE**
I tried to add:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT,BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>myRealm</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

after `</welcome-file-list>` in my `web.xml` but I still receive the **403 Error**.

Comment: I helped another user set up there security config when they got a 403 as well. Look into weblogic roles and the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27071244/oc4j-to-weblogic-12c-migration-and-security-configuration-questions/27138919#27138919

Comment: @DisplayNameismissing, reading docs I understand that, I need `roles` and `groups` if I want to set restriction. I just want to get `userName` from SSO.